# IQueryable and Count

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following:

```
IQueryable<ViewAccountEntry> viewAccountEntries = db.AccountEntries
    .Where(x => x.DEntryID == 0)
    .Select(x => new ViewAccountEntry()
    {
        AccountEntry = x,
        DAccountEntries = db.AccountEntries
            .Where(y => y.DEntryID == 0
                && y.Amount == -x.Amount
                && y.DateEntry == x.DateEntry)
            .ToList()
    });
    Pages = new PageInfo(viewAccountEntries.Count(), page);
    ViewAccountEntries = viewAccountEntries
        .OrderBy(x => x.AccountEntry.DateEntry)
        .Skip(Pages.ItemsSkipped)
        .Take(Pages.ItemsPerPage)
        .ToList();
```

Inside the first `Select()` an object is created containing a second list.

When the `.Count()` is executed, does it execute the fetch of the second `Select`? Or does it count intelligently, knowing it does not need to perform either `Select`?

Comment: Log the actual SQL being executed (and profile the database if that alone doesn't give you your answer) and find out for yourself.

Comment: No idea how to do either.

Comment: Then now's a good time to learn.  You should be checking the SQL of most LINQ queries you ever write (at least any complex ones) just to verify your work and make sure nothing wonky is going on behind the scenes.  As for how, that will vary based on the query provider, but each will expose a means of logging it.  The same can be said about inspecting the detailed execution plan of the query on the database end; look up your specific database.

Comment: However, I realised that I could create the first IQueryable to not have the select, and add on the select part later. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am using an MDF under Visual Studio.

Comment: Okay, I got a logger working. I can see that the count sql is simpler.

Comment: To @Servy's point I'd add that it's particularly worth checking the SQL of anything that uses `GroupBy`, since a lot of the exceptions to the rule that the query engine will generally pick a very efficient approach involve grouping; sometimes turning what could be a single DB query and some quick in-memory grouping into N+1 queries per group in the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Count()` is turned into the best implementation of `Count()` that the query engine knows about.

Database-backed query engines like Entity Framework or Linq2SQL will generally use something that causes `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(DISTINCT some_field)` or similar to be used in the SQL produced.

Other linq implementations will similarly try to be as clever as they can. For example, linq-to-objects will call the `Count` getter rather than enumerating through the whole enumeration if it's called on an object that implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`.

It is possible that a given query engine when dealing with a given use of `Count()` will end up having to cycle through an enumeration of items, because it can't figure out anything more efficient. As a rule, the more you keep things on terms of the initial type of Linq (e.g. don't call `ToList()` unless you need to, or even `AsEnumerable()` if you can get away with not doing so) the better the engine will do, though there are sometimes exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

As long you keep it `IQueryable` and not calling `ToList()`, EF is smart enough to optimise query and prevent any actual select on `Count()` query.